# Visual Studio 2013 Update 2 - code files corrupt randomly

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

This has been happening to me and others on my team, maybe once a week. We'll be debugging a web application project and then edit and save a text file that is part of the site (like a .aspx or .css files). The file will initially be fine in visual studio and look normal, but the output to the browser will be garbage. It's hard to know what's going on until you close the file in visual studio and try to re-open it. Visual studio will open the file in notepad for some reason, and you'll see all garbage characters.

[image: garbage characters]

To fix the problem I have to revert the file from TFS and any work not in TFS is lost.

We have Resharper 8.2.1 and the latest Telerik UI for Asp.net Ajax controls installed. Everything else is pretty standard setup for Visual Studio.

The web application project is set to use IIS Express.

Does anyone else ever have this problem, and know what might be causing it?

Edit: This just happened again, but this time with a class library project. So it doesn't seem to be exclusively a problem with web application projects.

Comment: Well, it seems pretty clear that in the process of  the "edit and save a text file" you're adding a BOM to the file that's resulting in a character set that isn't available. Open it with a hex editor and examine the first four bytes of the file to determine what that BOM is that you're writing. To figure out what's causing it, you'll need to debug your code and determine where the incorrect BOM is being written (or how you're saving the file that's resulting in it being added).

Comment: @KenWhite I ran the file through File BOM Detector, and it did not detect a valid BOM in the file. I also ran a non-corrupted file from my project through the BOM detector, and it came up fine as UTF-8.

Comment: Your screenshot is unhelpful, make the file available on a file sharing service so we can tell what might have happened from the character codes.  It is an environmental problem so do name things like anti-malware and firewall product, any custom CSS tooling and whether anybody might be using another source control program.

Comment: The same issue happening in VS2013 Update3 also. Its really annoying.

Comment: I posted the solution that worked for me. Check out my answer below. I hope it helps!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my case the problem had to do with the encryption software that is installed on my Dell laptop - "CREDANT Mobile Guardian Shield". If you have administrative access to this, then you can add exceptions so that it doesn't encrypt your project / solutions folders.

I don't have access to modify the exception list, so what I did was look through the exception list and found a path listed that looked suitable for placing files I work with. In my case I chose "C:\sources\". I reinstalled all of my tooling into c:\sources\apps\, and use c:\sources\projects\ for all my solution files / TFS workspaces. My apps run faster now because there's no encryption overhead, and I haven't had the file corruption problem since doing this about 2 months ago.

[image: this is the credant mobile guardian shield product info dialog]
[image: here's where you can find the exception list in that app]
[image: my non-encrypted folder setup]

Answer (score -1):

Notepad is believing that the text file is Unicode but it is ANSI. Change the file encoding to Unicode.